# Tweenlite adds transform to style instead of custom attribute

Tags: css, svg, gsap

I'm using scaling, rotating and moving image with tweenlite and draggable library.

```
TweenLite.to(image, 0, {rotation: value, transformOrigin:"50% 50%"});
TweenLite.to(image, 0, {scaleX: value, scaleY: value, transformOrigin:"50% 50%"});
Draggable.create(image, {type: "x,y", throwProps: true, zIndexBoost: false,
      force3D: false});
```

It works. The problem is that when I export svg, this svg doesn't work anywhere.
Library adds transform to style attribute:

```
 style="overflow: visible; cursor: move; touch-action: none; -webkit-user-  
select: none; transform: matrix(0.08244, 0, 0, 0.08244, 111, 17);"
```

How can i clear completely this style attribute when saving svg and add just transform as separate attribute:

```
transform="matrix(0.08244 0 0 0.08244 111 17)"
```

As I understand, there is some setting in library to use attr instead of style but can't find the way to do with attr.

Comment: you can go for `transform: none` if you want to clear it.

Comment: Are using the latest version of GSAP? (currently at version 1.18.0). What do you mean by `when I export svg` ? .. what are you exporting from? .. some additional info would be appreciated. as well as a codepen or jsfiddle example. So we can see your code live

Comment: yes, it is 1.18.0
What I mean is to not add transform into style like: 
<image style="transform:.." /> 
but as attribute: 
<image transform="..." />
Thats all. I save changed svg from client to server.If you open svg with image inside and image has transform inside style, it won't work in illustrator or Inkscape or IE...It works only in chrome(from the one I have tried).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link that describes a solution...

http://greensock.com/forums/topic/10684-apply-transforms-with-transform-attr-instead-of-inline-style-on-svg/

Comment: I have already tried this but it doesn't work.:
Draggable.create(image, {attr:{type: "x,y", throwProps: true, zIndexBoost: false,force3D: false}});
Should I change something?